# Dealing with added and deleted files in a git merge

Tags: git

In my repository I have two branches: master and dev. There has been a lot of activity on the dev branch and I need to merge it back into master, but I'm having trouble finding the right way to do it.

If I do a straightforward `git merge dev` then it creates conflicts in files that have only changed in the dev branch. Worse, if I open those files in the merge tool then the 'merged' version has the contents from the master branch.

`git merge dev -X theirs` gets closer and those files are now correctly merged. The remaining problem I've got is it's not properly handling files which have been added and deleted in the branch. For files which have been added in the branch I get this conflict:

> CONFLICT (modify/delete): my_added_file deleted in HEAD and modified
>   in dev. Version dev of my_added_file left in tree.

This is not really an issue as I can just resolve it as 'modify', which takes the branch version. The problem is with files that have been deleted in the branch are not being deleted in the merge. What am I missing?

---

Update: Ok well I can see why git is confused. Somehow a random commit in master has been parented to a completely unrelated commit in dev. How do I fix this??

The blue line is dev and the purple line is master.

[image: git log]

Comment: you want to rebase dev over master, so that all commits to master are  in the "past" of dev branch file deletions.

Comment: What other activity is occurring on your master branch?  If there are no other commits on master, then this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I've looked at rebasing, but I was under the impression that wasn't appropriate given the repository is shared with other people? There's not been much activity on master besides the odd bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to have done this, but here's what I ultimately ended up doing. The repository is hosted on Bitbucket, which made things a bit more challenging as I had to rewrite the history.

1. Rewrite the branch to remove the offending parent: `git filter-branch --parent-filter "sed 's/-p 12eed45e184246c0553e410734f83d226bf9bd4f//'" master`
2. Rename the `master` branch to `master_new`
3. Push `master_new` to Bitbucket
4. Set the main branch on Bitbucket to `master_new`
5. Delete `master` on Bitbucket
6. Delete `origin/master` locally
7. Rename `master_new` to `master` locally
8. Push `master` to Bitbucket
9. Set the main branch on Bitbucket to `master`
10. Delete `master_new` on Bitbucket
11. Get everyone else to do a fresh checkout

After this I was able to complete the merge normally.